# Is the DbContext disposed when I do a ToList() in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I read that, with **EF Core**, it is not obligated to use a using statement with the **`DBContext`** to dispose of it (or to call the de Dispose method directly). The garbage collector will do it. I also read that when you read the objects you've retrieved, they should dispose of too, but I am not sure if I understand correctly. Does it mean that if I do a `toList()` on a collection return by my DbContext, that my context will be disposed of at this moment? I have difficulties finding this specific answer on Google.

Comment: No, it does not mean that.  If it did, it would mean you could ever only make one query with one `DbContext`, which is definitely not the case.

Comment: In .Net Core we register DBContext as any other service. And while registering we specify the scope of the object so created .. Transient, Scoped & Singleton. And accordingly once the lifespan of that object is completed it would be disposed.

Comment: This is not per se related to EF or DbContexts, it's about the basics of C# concerning `IDisposable`, object scope and lifetime. That's too much to explain here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource management of Entity Framework does not work in that manner.  Entity Framework explicitly defines the lifetime when an instance created until the instance is disposed of.  When the framework was developed, the fundamental purpose was to exist within a single unit-of-work which is why it is well suited for web applications, it can be used elsewhere- but the fundamental usage fit.

How you configure and scope your service will define the lifetime of the instance.  But it should adhere to the following principals:

> Typical unit-of-work would involve the creation of an instance, the tracking of the entity instances defined on the context, returned from query, added or attached to the context, change being made to the tracked entities.  Then save those changes made and write them to the database.  Then disposal of the instance.

So if you leverage a service such as:

```
public class CustomerAccountService : ICustomerAccountService
{
     private bool disposed = false;
     private readonly ICustomerRepository repository;

     public CustomerAccountService(ICustomerRepository repository) => this.repository = repository;

    // Additional logic would go here, including the implementation of the repository which will hold our DbContext.
}
```

When the `CustomerAccountService` is no longer scoped, then it would begin to clean dispose and clean up the Entity Framework instance as the lifetime has expired once the service.  Keep in mind that the Dependency Injection container and your configuration will impact how this will be impacted.  If you can, you should always add an `IDispose` that correctly reallocates those resources.

The documentation explicitly states:

> It is very important to dispose the DbContext after use. This ensures both that any unmanaged resources are freed, and that any events or other hooks are unregistered so as to prevent memory leaks in case the instance remains referenced.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer ! The reason I asked this question is because we have an application split into layers : Data Access Layer, Business Logic Layer and Presentation Layer. Where I work, we tend to give the responsability of creating the query (ex: Where id = id) to the business layer, but some people don't like having to use using statement to call the dbContext in the business layer, so we are looking for best practices or other ways to work with the dbcontext, hence my question.

Comment: Yeah, should be okay if you wrap the database context in a factory pattern, then when you call the factory the dispose would be defined for the DI Framework to handle the lifetime.